# Angular 4 How to Share variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I am loading app component first and based on routing loading other pages.

After Loading first page, I wanna share app component variable to search component. Both are loading on first page. How can I do this?

```
change(lan) {
  // I wanna send this lan variable to search component,   
  // this time search component loaded already in routing
}
```

The flow is like this:

First time search component and app component are loaded.

After that I will change a variable.

That should available for me in search component.

`HTML`

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="height-40 col-xs-12 bgcolor-EF bottom-panel">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="change('en')">English</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="change('pa')">Español</a>
</div>
```

`TS`

```
change(lan) {

}
```

How to retrieve in Search component?

Comment: What about `Input`s?

Comment: You can share it throw a service which share by components

Comment: @CristianTraìna I didn't try with that.

Comment: @mickaelw I try to share with service, it's not sharing. Bcz, that loading app component and search component are loading. After that I am changing some variable in app component and should trigger in search component, which already loaded..

Comment: @Veera if I understand your question, when you change the language you want notify the other components of that change?

Comment: @mickaelw yes ri8

Comment: It's more complex we need the code of your search component (.ts) where you lunch the search

Comment: In routing.<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: Yes I think, maybe you have a SearchComponent?

Comment: Yes we have search component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend to build a service for you use-case.
You will subscribe to the service in the search component and wait for updates. In the app component you will send an update to the service as soon as the language is changed. This uses the principe of observables, which is a big part of angular. In the example I used BehaviorSubject instead of normal Subjects/Observable, because they will give you a default value (or the last updated value they received) as soon as you subscribe.

Those are the basics:

**LanService**

```
export class LanService{

  //default language
  private lan:BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('en');

  public getLan(){
    return this.lan.asObservable();
  }

  public updateLan(lan){
    this.lan.next(lan);
  }
}
```

**SearchComponent**

```
constructor(private ls:LanService){
  this.ls.getLan().subscribe(lan => console.log(lan));
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
change(lan){
  this.ls.updateLan(lan); //assuming you injected ls:LanService in constructor
}
```

Comment: It's not sharing. Bcz, I am loading app component and search component once. After that I am changing some variable in app component and not triggering that in search component

Comment: @Veera this is correct. You only load app and search component once. But thats why you need to `.subscribe`. This method will get an update as soon as you update the service. It will trigger the search component automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods by which you can accomplish your desired goal:

1. Create a shared service (provide it in the root module so you have only one instance of it), store a property on it and share across components
2. Use some kind of a store system, like [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx)
3. Use `Input`-s and `Output`-s and alert changes to parent component so it changes it for all children

Any of this solutions will work, depending on your task you may chose any of them.

Comment: Please share with an example

Comment: You should provide your own code before expecting anyone to post examples of solutions. For example, if your components are children of the same parent component, I may use one solution, if they are separated across the DOM, I may use another approach.

Comment: Updated question, please check

Comment: Still no clue to how your components are related to each other (whether they siblings, or parent-child)

Answer (score 0):

Well the best thing to do would be to create a Shared Service and register it a level up in the heirarchy

or Just keep a shared service for your whole app and inject it wherever needed.

Comment: It's not working. Bcz, I am loading app component and search component once. After that I am changing some variable in app component and not triggering that in search component

Comment: @Veera observables might come in handy

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do with **Input Output**
Let's i guess your flow of your html and give solution

> First page html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>First page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-component (onSearchChange)="onSearchChange($event)"></app-component>
        <search-component [searchValue]="searchValue"></search-compoenent>
    </body>
</html>
```

> First page ts

```
public searchValue:any
onSearchChange(data:any){
    this.searchValue = data;
}
```

> app-component html

```
<div>
        <input [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
    </div>
```

> app-component.ts

```
@Output() onSearchChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
onChange(){
    this.onSearchChange.emit(this.selectedItem);
}
```

> Search compoenent ts

```
@Input() public searchValue: any;
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (typeof changes.searchValue !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('filter changes value',changes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am loading search component by routing in app.component.html <router-outlet></router-outlet>